# How to extract from a text in python

Tags: python, regex, text, extract

Let's say we have text within which column are stored in the form:

```
! Column1<NEWLINE>! Column2<NEWLINE>! Column3<NEWLINE>! Column4<NEWLINE>
```

Example text :

```
 class="wikitable" style="float:right; text-align:center; margin:2em;"<NEWLINE>|+ Comparison of Union and Confederacy, 1860–1864<ref name="census74" /><NEWLINE>! id<NEWLINE>! Year<NEWLINE>! Union<NEWLINE>! Confederacy<NEWLINE>|-<NEWLINE>|rowspan="2"|'''Population'''<NEWLINE>|1860<NEWLINE>| 22,100,000 (71%)<NEWLINE>| 9,100,000 (29%)<NEWLINE>|-<NEWLINE>|1864<NEWLINE>| 28,800,000 (90%)
```

How can I extract all the column from the text in python?

I tried

```
re.findall('NEWLINE>!\s*([^|]+)', text, re.MULTILINE)
```

https://regex101.com/r/PLKREz/8

Comment: use an html parser.

Answer (score 0):

You can just do a split.

`split_text = text.split("<NEWLINE>!")`

If you want to skip the first ! also, you can do:
`split_text = text[1:].split("<NEWLINE>!")`

Answer (score 0):

re.findall('NEWLINE>!\s*([^<]+)', text, re.MULTILINE)
maybe you can try this. the code is a little difference from [^|] to [^<] and it can extract the four columns.